# Is there a standard way to define the content of a CSV file?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

Although CSV files optionally contain column headers to define what columns are within the file, I am interested in knowing if there is a standard or common approach for defining the expected data types.

I guess I am looking for something that is akin to an xsd file that defines the data within an xml file (I don't really know much about this subject either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into the SQL Server BCP utility. This GUI front end for the utility suggests that the tools uses a format file to define the contents of the output file.--at least, that's the impression that I get. I haven't looked into it much yet, but this looks like something like what I was looking for...

[image]

USE [PandaVisa2011]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Shipper]    Script Date: 06/27/2011 22:05:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shipper](
    [ShipperId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ShortName] [varchar](30) NULL) ON [PRIMARY
```

]

```
10.0
3
1       SQLCHAR             0       12      ","        1     ShipperId              ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","        2     Name                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       30      "\r\r\n"   3     ShortName              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 1):

CSV defines a way to represent rows and columns. It does not defined what those rows and columns contain, or whether or not the first row represents a header.

As far as a "command", I'm not really sure exactly what you are trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to write "Common", not "Command". I edited the text above. when I use SSIS or EXCEL or whatever to import a CSV file, these apps sample the data and guess what data types to apply to each of the column based on the data that it sees in a sampled number of rows. What I would like to do is have a standard process that validates a CSV file much like you can validate an XML file using an associated XSD file.

Comment: When I request a source system to provide a CSV file, I don't want to use Word to document the expected layout. I want to use a extract utility that is aware of the file format definition and throws an exception if the extract program attempts to extract data that violates this expected definition. On the load side, I want the load utility to likewise inform me if the file doesn't conform to the expect format, or even be able to programmatically separate those that do fron those that dont in a standard reusable way.

Comment: I'm expecting that the answer is "there ain't any" but I think there should be a way (by now!)

Comment: @Velika: I really didn't follow all that. So I'll just repeat that there is nothing about CSV that defines what data should be included. If you want to define it further, then I think you would need to come up with your own way of doing that.

Comment: Are you familiar with how xsd files define the content of an xml file?

Comment: @Velika: Somewhat. I'm not aware of anything like that for CSV.

Comment: @Velika: I don't see how that does what you asked, but glad you feel you've found a solution.